# Preserving a JWT token after login

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, jwt

I'm very new to NodeJS so this is probably quite low-level but I have tried SO many different 'solutions' here.

I am using NodeJS, MongoDB and Express with Vanilla JS (being rendered through Pug). My project follows an MVC structure.

---

### Problem

So far:

- I can login a user successfully, and have the correct messages returned.
- A JWT token is created as I have checked by printing it to the console.
- Immediately after the JWT is created I can access the user using promisify:

  ```js
     const decode = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_S);
     const currentAccount = await Account.findById(decode.id);
     console.log(currentAccount);
  ```
- However, I cannot then access this token / it is **`undefined`** when I attempt to run another function, such as loading data to the next page following the login success.

This functionality works like this:

- The page route contains a call to a `loadData` function, which should (for now) just load the user account data.
- This function is in `accountController.js`.
- The `login` function is `authController.js`.
- It calls a `createToken` function which correctly creates a token and returns it.
- After exiting the `login` function, I can no longer access the token and attempting to get the `currentUser` in the `loadData` function does not work, as the `currentUser` is **`undefined`**.
- It might be useful to know that it works with Postman - I can call functions that require the current user.
- **NEW** When I print `req.headers` before getting the user, there is no `authorization` field.
- **NEW** Printing `req.cookies.JWT` is **`undefined`**.
- It might be useful to note that `loadData` is called on page load, through the `accountRouter`. There are no problems with the code for this router.

---

### Code

`accountController.js` / `loadData`

```js
exports.loadData = async (req, res, next) => {
    const currentAccount = await getCurrentAccount(req);
    console.log(currentAccount) // undefined
    next();
};
```

`accountController.js` / `getCurrentAccount`

```js
const getCurrentAccount = async (req) => {
    let token;
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')) {
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.cookies.JWT) {
        token = req.cookies.JWT;
    }

    if (token) {
        const decode = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token, process.env.JWT_S);
        const currentAccount = await Account.findById(decode.id);

        return currentAccount;
    }
    return undefined; // this is running
}
```

`authController.js` / `login`

```js
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  if (!email || !password) {
    return next(new AppError("Email and Password required.", 400));
  }

  // '+' overrides 'select: false' in the password item of accountModel
  const account = await Account.findOne({ email }).select("+password");

  if (!account || !(await account.correctPassword(password, account.password))
  ) {
    return next(new AppError("Incorrect email or password", 401));
  }

  var token = createToken(account, 200, res);

  // remove password from output
  const accountCopy = account;
  accountCopy.password = undefined;

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'Success',
    token,
    data: {
      account: accountCopy
    }
  });
};
```

`authController.js` / `createToken`

```js
const createToken = (account, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = signToken(account._id);
  const cookieOptions = {
    httpOnly: true
  };

  // Send over HTTPS when the app is deployed rather than HTTP
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') cookieOptions.secure = true;
  res.cookie('JWT', token, cookieOptions);

  return token;
};
```

`authController.js` / `signToken`

```js
const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id }, process.env.JWT_S, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXP,
  });
};
```

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "./public/js/bundle.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "crypto": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "http": "^0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.5.3",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.10",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "util": "^0.12.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
    "start-prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js",
    "watch:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir --public-url ./public/js --out-file bundle.js",
    "build:js": "parcel watch ./public/js/index.js --out-dir --public-url ./public/js --out-file bundle.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.12.3",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

---

Would anyone be able to help me figure out what to do?

Comment: if `if (token) {` is not true, then check the lines above, it's likely the issue is in the client not sending the cookie and/or setting the request headers

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks - it seems there is no `authorization` field in the headers.

Comment: It also seems that printing `req.cookies.JWT` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `createToken` function anywhere in your `login` handler so the `token` variable in your json response is undefined.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my code - unfortunately this wasn't the problem as I just somehow missed copying over that single line to the question

Comment: @Chris Did you find the actual problem? Also make sure that you have set up the cookie-parser middleware otherwise the `req.cookies` will be undefined.